# Using elisp, how to start, send-keys-to, and stop a command in emacs terminal emulator?

Tags: linux, emacs, elisp

Using `elisp` (not interactive key-chords), how can I run a command in `emacs` terminal emulator; and how can I send key-presses to that buffer?

Starting `term` seems to require `(term "/bin/bash")`, which has no scope for running a command.  I assume that might be because *term* is intended as an interactive tool...

Also I want to send specific keys to the running app. Can this be done. I thought (insert 'x) might work, but it doesn't have a buffer parameter, nor does it allow for M- C- S- s-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send input directly to the terminal with `term-send-raw-string`.  Example:

```
(progn
  (set-buffer "*terminal*")
  (term-send-raw-string "ls -l\n"))
```

This will simulate the effect of typing `ls -l`<kbd>RET</kbd> into the terminal buffer.

While `term` isn't very flexible about argument parsing, it's usually sufficient to start up a shell and feed it commands with `term-send-raw-string` to load up the target program.  Here's a little piece of elisp that scripts some commands to an interactive program:

```
(progn 
  (let ((term-buffer (term "/bin/bash")))
    (set-buffer term-buffer)

    ;; start up vi
    (term-send-raw-string "vi hello.txt\n")

    ;; some line noise :P
    (term-send-raw-string "ihello world\033:wq\n")

    ;; quit our shell
    (term-send-raw-string "exit")))
```

Comment: *@ataylor:* Thanks.. That's been a great help to get an elisp newbie, like me, rolling.. It led me to discover the many other `term-*` commands.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you can also try:

```
(with-current-buffer "*terminal*" 
  (term-send-raw-string "ls -l\n"))
```